# Suricata rule for SQLI

Tags: suricata

I need some help am still new to suricata. am learning and my splunk event shows theres an automated SQLI attack .

```
10.157.31.87 - - [02/Jan/2021:17:30:50 +0000] "GET /images.php?id=bXlzcWwgLS11c2VyPXJvb3QgLS1wYXNzd29yZD1yb290Cg== HTTP/1.1" 200 31 "-" "curl/7.58.0"
```

This is my rule i wrote seems its not stopping the attack.

```
drop http $EXTERNAL_NET  any <> 192.168.10.2 any (msg:"sql bruteforce"; priority: 1; uricontent:"GET /images.php?"; sid:10000001; rev: 1;)
```

192.168.10 .2 is the  ip for my web server

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

`drop http any any -> 192.168.10.2 any (msg:"Malicious php code injection in an images.php file"; priority: 1; http.method; http.uri; content:"GET"; content:"/images.php?"; sid:10000001; rev: 1;)`

It will work with all the requests to your server **192.168.10.2**, in **GET** method with "**/images.php?**" in the URI.